# How to show an animation item on recyclerview overscroll and then bounce back?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am looking to show an item that is animated upon overscroll instead of the default tint overlay.

There would be a small animation and then bounced back.

This is the full sequence:

1. User horizontally swipes to end
2. User overscrolls
3. An animation is shown that is the size of a standard item (we are using lottie to show the animation)
4. at the end of the animation the reyclerview bounces back to not being overscrolled

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have a reyclerview adapter that contains a footerview with an animation. When the user has scrolled near the end I start the animatinon the footerview and when it is done I scroll the reyclerview back so that the footerview is off the screen.

```
private void configureFooterItemAnimation(RecyclerView itemRecyclerView, LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager,
        ProductRecyclerAdapter productRecyclerAdapter) {

    int productWidth = activity.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.product_footer_width_plus_15);

    itemRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int dx, final int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            if (recyclerView.getScrollState() == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)  {
                return;
            }

            if (linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() == productRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount() -1) {

                final LottieAnimationView footerView = productRecyclerAdapter.getFooterView();

                if (!footerView.isAnimating()) {
                    footerView.addAnimatorListener(new AnimatorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(final Animator animation) {
                            itemRecyclerView.setOnTouchListener(getConsumeAllEventsOnTouchListener());
                            itemRecyclerView.scrollBy(dpToPx(activity, 230), 0);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(final Animator animation) {
                            itemRecyclerView.scrollBy(-productWidth, 0);
                            footerView.removeAllAnimatorListeners();
                            itemRecyclerView.setOnTouchListener(null);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationCancel(final Animator animation) {

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(final Animator animation) {

                        }
                    });
                    footerView.playAnimation();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

@NonNull
private OnTouchListener getConsumeAllEventsOnTouchListener() {
    return new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```